# Orientation not working with toast view

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation

I have include the toast class, i have assigned my application as portrait in iphone and landscape in ipad when i work with following code

```
customView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 54)] autorelease];
[customView setBackgroundColor: UIColorFromRGB(0xda5340)];
UILabel *lb1=[[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 17, 180, 21)] autorelease];
lb1.text=@"Pet is out of boundary";
lb1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
lb1.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
lb1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[customView addSubview:lb1];
[self.window showToast:customView duration:3.0 position:@"top" ];
```

[image][image]

in iphone its shows properly in exact postion.

when I try with ipad it shows vertically like as in the image.

Please help me to sort it out.

Comment: Hi,Sorry but i have added your code in ipad and iphone in ios 6.0 and it is working perfectly

Comment: My above code was in app delegate,did you try with app delegate or nor view?

Answer (score 0):

Hi,                                                                                      Sorry but i have added your code in ipad and iphone in ios 6.0 and it is working perfectly if we add the code in view and  i changed in this way the code

```
 #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_6_0
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
      return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
    }
    else{
      return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
    }
}
#endif
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
    }
    else{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

Comment: My above code was in app delegate,did you try with app delegate or nor view?